# Scrolling div programmatically on word match in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have written a program such that when a user type a word in a textbox all the matching words in a div gets highlighted. I have prev and next button which is used for navigation. The div also have scrollbars in case the text overflows. Now What i want to do is as i click next button and if the word is highlighted at very bottom of the page i want my scrollbar to scroll automatically upto that particular word or element using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer without a code sample. But presumably you have some way of selecting the highlighted word already, if that's the case then you can just scroll to it like:

```
$("#nextButtonId").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#highlightedWordId").offset().top
     }, 1500);
 });
```

Comment: my word is highlighted as <span class='highlight'>word</span> Class highlight contains code as ".highlight{background:red;}" and there may be 100's of word matching in a text, that's the reason i haven't used id for word match

Comment: Can you select it as $("span.highlight").first() then, and scroll to that ? Maybe you'd have to refine it more than that, it's impossible to say without seeing the code.